# reCAPTCHA Gem: How Can I Suppress The Error Message in my Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, recaptcha

I just installed the reCAPTCHA gem in my Rails 5.1 app. I'm using the v2 checkbox. I use custom flash messages for errors on my contact form. I have my custom error message defined in my controller if someone does not check the checkbox. The gem displays the error "**reCAPTCHA verification failed, please try again.** at the top left corner of the screen above the normal top of my screen. I would like to suppress that error message since I'm already displaying my custom flash error message.

Here is my code in my controller:

```
  if verify_recaptcha
    ......my contact form is submitted......
  else
    flash[:danger] = "My custom reCAPTCHA message"
    render :home
  end
```

I have searched for this but I have not found any examples of this being done. I also have not found any instructions in the gem documentation. The documentation link does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove it from the flash

```
if verify_recaptcha
  ......my contact form is submitted......
else
  flash.delete(:recaptcha_error)
  flash[:danger] = "My custom reCAPTCHA message"
  render :home
end
```